# Ubuntu touch smartphones

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mobile-broadband

Are there any smartphones available in **India** with **Ubuntu Mobile OS**? If not, is it possible to install ubuntu touch in android tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no Ubuntu Touch smartphones available at retail in India or anywhere else.

There are a couple of tablet devices that Ubuntu Touch currently supports if you're willing to install it yourself. [They are the Nexus 7 2013 WiFi and the Nexus 10](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/).

[Here are the instructions detailing how to install Ubuntu Touch](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/).

Comment: can we install it on any android device?

Comment: @shubhangsati no, unfortunately only the Nexus 7 & 10 are officially supported. There are ubuntu images available for other devices, but they're unofficial ports that are buggy and not supported. You can find a full list here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices